# External Disk, extended journaled with password, suddenly starts without password query

Tags: macbook-pro, high-sierra, hardware, password, external-disk

my External DiskLaCie hard drive D2 Quadra USB3, extended journaled with password, 
appears on the screen the next morning without a password query.
On my MacBook Pro and on the hard drive no updates etc. where made.
Now even after restart and delete the PR VRAM etc it always starts without a password query ...
On "infos" in the disk utility, I see that the disk is still password protected and journaled...
I have an other External Disk (the same product), she still starts with password query, so what has happened on my mac or with the external disk over night?
Apple MacBook Pro 13 Zoll
MacOsHigh Sierra V 10.13.6

PS. LA Cie/Seagate Support says, that i shall ask the apple support, and vice versa...

Comment: Sounds like the password may have been saved in your keychain...

Comment: what could be the name of this keychain? im looking in my keychain administration

Comment: there is no key with name of the external-disk or "LaCie" etc